# Click - Add text - Active textbox

Tags: javascript, string, text, onclick, addition

I would like to add text to the active textbox when a button is clicked.

I have read many threads explaining how it is done when one is wishing to add to a specific textbox but nothing on simply adding text to whichever text field is active...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't one `textbox` in the world, what technology / platform are you talking about?

Comment: Apologies. I'm looking to make a javascript function that will simulate typing a string a letters on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below is a solution for a *virtual keyboard*.

Pure JS + HTML:

```js
function bind()  {
  var keyArr = document.getElementsByClassName('key');
  for(var i = 0; i < keyArr.length; i++)  {
    keyArr[i].addEventListener('click', function()  {
      document.getElementById('textinput').value += this.innerHTML;
    });
  }
  var capsLock = document.getElementById('capslock');
  capsLock.addEventListener('click', function()  {
    for(var i = 0; i < keyArr.length; i++)  {
      if(capsLock.capsactive)  {
        keyArr[i].innerHTML = keyArr[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      }  else  {
        keyArr[i].innerHTML = keyArr[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase();
      }
    }
    capsLock.capsactive = !capsLock.capsactive;
  });
}
```

```html
<body onload='bind()'>
  <input id='textinput'><br>
  <button class='key'>q</button>
  <button class='key'>w</button>
  <button class='key'>e</button>
  <button class='key'>r</button>
  <button class='key'>t</button>
  <button class='key'>y</button><br>
  <button id='capslock' capsactive=false>CapsLock</button>
</body>
```

You can access a textbox's `value` by `element.value` or by `$(selector).val()`.
For changing, use: `element.value = newvalue;` *(JS)* or `$(selector).val(newvalue);` (*jQuery*).

In the example, `...addEventListener...` attaches a function to each button. The function, here, changes the value of the `textinput` textbox, to be the previous value + the text of the button which was pressed.
For instance, if the even the `capsLock` button is given the class `key`, on clicking `capsLock`, the text `"Caps Lock"` will be appended to the textbox.

Note: This solution covers adding text to a definite field. If there are multiple textbox-es present on the page, and the text has to be added to the currently focused one, a different approach has to be taken:

```js
var lfl = -1, capsactive = false;
$(document).ready(function()  {
  $('*').blur(function()  {
    lfl = this;
  });
  $('.key').click(function()  {
    if($(lfl).hasClass('vkballowed'))  {
      $(lfl).val($(lfl).val() + $(this).html());
      $(lfl).focus();
    }
  });
  $('#capslock').click(function()  {
    capsactive = !capsactive;
    if(capsactive == true)  {
      $('.key').each(function()  {
        $(this).html($(this).html().toUpperCase());
      });
    }  else  {
      $('.key').each(function()  {
        $(this).html($(this).html().toLowerCase());
      });
    }
    $(lfl).focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='input0' class='vkballowed'><p>Editable</p><br>
<input id='input1' class='vkballowed'><p>Editable</p><br>
<input id='input2'><p>Not Editable</p><br>
<button class='key'>q</button>
<button class='key'>w</button>
<button class='key'>e</button>
<button class='key'>r</button>
<button class='key'>t</button>
<button class='key'>y</button><br>
<button id='capslock'>CapsLock</button>
```

Example instructions: Focus on the `Editable` text-fields, then press a key on the virtual-keyboard, so that corresponding text is appended to the fields. The virtual-keyboard doesn't work on the `Not Editable` text-field.

Here, the last element on the page that lost focus *(was `blur`red)* is stored in a variable. Next, whenever a key on the virtual-keyboard is pressed, first, it is checked whether the keyboard is allowed on that control, then the button's text is appended to the control, and finally, the control is given its focus back. Note that if the class `vkballowed` is added to controls such as `button`s, no action would be effective on those controls. On other controls such as `textarea`s, which have a `value` property, the virtual-keyboard will be functional.

The above approach isn't wholly correct. If, for instance, a key on the virtual-keyboard is pressed right after some other interactive button on the page, that button would receive focus again *(this may not re-cause the action attached to that button, though)*. It, hopefully, gives you a starting point though.

Answer (score 0):

jquery

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(event) {
 $('.tstboxClass').val('heelo i am text box value.');
})
```